# Kaldi error while running script prepare_lang.sh -- GenericRegister::GetEntry: No such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, kaldi, openfst, fst

I am using Kaldi to train an acoustic model on my own dataset (following [this](https://eleanorchodroff.com/tutorial/kaldi/index.html) tutorial by Eleanor Chodroff). I'm using Cygwin on Windows 10. When I run the script `prepare_lang.sh` that should create the files for `/data/lang`, it generates the following errors:

```
ERROR: GenericRegister::GetEntry: No such file or directory
ERROR: MutableFst::Read: Unknown FST type "vector" (arc type = "standard"): standard input
```

These files are not created: `L.fst, L_disambig.fst, oov.int, oov.txt, topo`

The complete output of the command is given below:

```
91767@LAPTOP-E2QH3TON /cygdrive/c/Users/91767/Desktop/kaldi/egs/mycorpus
$ utils/prepare_lang.sh data/local/lang oov data/local/ data/lang

utils/prepare_lang.sh data/local/lang oov data/local/ data/lang
Checking data/local/lang/silence_phones.txt ...
--> reading data/local/lang/silence_phones.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/lang/silence_phones.txt is OK

Checking data/local/lang/optional_silence.txt ...
--> reading data/local/lang/optional_silence.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/lang/optional_silence.txt is OK

Checking data/local/lang/nonsilence_phones.txt ...
--> reading data/local/lang/nonsilence_phones.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/lang/nonsilence_phones.txt is OK

Checking disjoint: silence_phones.txt, nonsilence_phones.txt
--> disjoint property is OK.

Checking data/local/lang/lexicon.txt
--> reading data/local/lang/lexicon.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/lang/lexicon.txt is OK

Checking data/local/lang/lexiconp.txt
--> reading data/local/lang/lexiconp.txt
--> text seems to be UTF-8 or ASCII, checking whitespaces
--> text contains only allowed whitespaces
--> data/local/lang/lexiconp.txt is OK

Checking lexicon pair data/local/lang/lexicon.txt and data/local/lang/lexiconp.txt
--> lexicon pair data/local/lang/lexicon.txt and data/local/lang/lexiconp.txt match

Checking data/local/lang/extra_questions.txt ...
--> data/local/lang/extra_questions.txt is empty (this is OK)
--> SUCCESS [validating dictionary directory data/local/lang]

ERROR: GenericRegister::GetEntry: No such file or directory
ERROR: MutableFst::Read: Unknown FST type "vector" (arc type = "standard"): standard input
```

I have followed the standard Kaldi installation for Cygwin from [the same tutorial](https://eleanorchodroff.com/tutorial/kaldi/index.html), and `kaldi/tools` has the folder `openfst-1.7.2`.

I have been googling this for a while, but can't seem to find a solution. I'm new to Kaldi and not sure about the source of the error, so I'll be happy to provide any other details that might be relevant. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: from the windows install note "However, note that the Windows setup is becoming out of date and is not regularly tested, and not all the may compile."  So you are on your own as upstream does not really support it.

Comment: Hi @matzeri, I believe that is about the native Windows install? I compiled it on Cygwin; should have made that clearer. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I'm not sure whether this would have solved the issue for OP, but I experienced the same error when trying to build Kaldi from commit 9af2c5c16 with OpenFST 1.7.2.

For whatever reason, using `--enable-bin --enable-static --enable-shared=no` does not statically link binaries (fstinfo etc), but also does not build the dynamic libraries necessary for those binaries to function.  I needed to remove the `--enable-shared=no` switch.

On Windows, you may need to do even more work to ensure the dynamic libraries are actually loaded. Try calling `fstinfo <your.fst>` on its own to see if you get the same missing library error; if so, try copying the OpenFST .dll or .lib files (I don't know what exactly gets built on Windows) to the same directory you are calling `fstinfo` from.